# Error compiling 'diesel' while installing Sui on virtual Ubuntu machine using Rust and Cargo

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-diesel, sui

It's my first public question here, I'm sorry if it lacks any information.
I'm trying to install Sui [install Sui](https://docs.sui.io/devnet/build/install) on a virtual Ubuntu machine on WSL2.
This is using Rust, although I'm aswell pretty new to this.
Before installing Sui, I installed the prerequisites detailed in the page below, and then tried to build sui binaries using :

```
cargo install --locked --git https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui.git --branch devnet sui
```

However by doing so, the cargo installer encounters an error compiling "diesel", which aborts the process :

```
error: could not compile `diesel`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `rustc --crate-name diesel --edition=2018 /home/antoine/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/diesel-2.0.3/src/lib.rs 
--error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts,future-incompat 
--diagnostic-width=120 --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C opt-level=3 -C panic=abort 
-C embed-bitcode=no -C split-debuginfo=packed -C debuginfo=1 --cfg 'feature="32-column-tables"' 
--cfg 'feature="64-column-tables"' --cfg 'feature="bitflags"' --cfg 'feature="byteorder"' 
--cfg 'feature="chrono"' --cfg 'feature="default"' 
--cfg 'feature="i-implement-a-third-party-backend-and-opt-into-breaking-changes"' --cfg 'feature="itoa"'
--cfg 'feature="postgres"' --cfg 'feature="postgres_backend"' --cfg 'feature="pq-sys"' 
--cfg 'feature="r2d2"' --cfg 'feature="serde_json"' --cfg 'feature="with-deprecated"' 
-C metadata=910cbefe446c683d -C extra-filename=-910cbefe446c683d 
--out-dir /tmp/cargo-installjxLb2t/release/deps -C strip=debuginfo 
-L dependency=/tmp/cargo-installjxLb2t/release/deps 
--extern bitflags=/tmp/cargo-installjxLb2t/release/deps/libbitflags-e5949a39186627ea.rmeta 
--extern byteorder=/tmp/cargo-installjxLb2t/release/deps/libbyteorder-2d235bc7037b2d93.rmeta 
--extern chrono=/tmp/cargo-installjxLb2t/release/deps/libchrono-2b0c9aaf0e3f3a01.rmeta 
--extern diesel_derives=/tmp/cargo-installjxLb2t/release/deps/libdiesel_derives-c7bad2300e3f2750.so 
--extern itoa=/tmp/cargo-installjxLb2t/release/deps/libitoa-353c8ba210cb8889.rmeta
--extern pq_sys=/tmp/cargo-installjxLb2t/release/deps/libpq_sys-48f4ec31a3125d17.rmeta 
--extern r2d2=/tmp/cargo-installjxLb2t/release/deps/libr2d2-e4794e946ea0d116.rmeta 
--extern serde_json=/tmp/cargo-installjxLb2t/release/deps/libserde_json-fc3f78b6b0c3ee9f.rmeta 
--cap-lints allow -L native=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` (signal: 9, SIGKILL: kill)
```

I added returns between args in the hope to make it clearer if it can help.
I don't really know what I am doing, but I am ready to provide any ressource you'd need to help me solve this issue, as long as you can explain me how to get it.

To identify the issue, I looked for other issues concerning building "diesel_cli", which looked to be related to "diesel", which were solved by installing other dependencies that I then installed, but it didn't solve my issue.
I also tried to build only "diesel_cli" :

```
cargo install diesel_cli
```

Which worked, but still didn't allow me to build the whole sui package :(

Comment: `SIGKILL` often means the OS killed the process for using too much memory.

Comment: Ok, didn't see that, is there ways to fix that, or does that mean I just don't have enough memory to run it ?
I have 16GB memory, but don't know if all is used by WSL

Answer (score 1):

If you are installing `diesel_cli` only for PostgreSQL.

First you need to install `libpq` in Ubuntu you can install it this way.

```
sudo apt install libpq-dev
```

After that you can install `diesel_cli` with postgreSQL features only. Maybe you need to uninstall `diesel_cli` first.

```
cargo uninstall diesel_cli
```

```
cargo install diesel_cli --features=postgres --no-default-features
```

Then try to install `sui` crate